# sql subquery from table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables (I am using T-SQL)

```
Table1

ID  First_Name Last_Name Phone
--  ---------- --------- --------------
1   John       Smith     (643) 434-4343 
2   Dave       Miller    (543) 344-3432
3   Tiffany    Ovally    (434) 343-6598
4   Dan        Davis     (534) 342-9876
5   Mike       Kolis     (454) 345-3434


Table2

Iden   FirstN     LastN      PhoneN
----   ------     -----      ------
J-09   Tiffany    Ovally    (434) 343-6598
K-98   Dan        Davis     (534) 342-9876
W-03   Dave       Miller    (543) 344-3432
C-34   Mike       Kolis     (454) 345-3434
```

I need to check that key values from Table1 DO NOT exist in table2

I am doing the following

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.FirstN = (Select First_Name from Table1 where ID = @ID)
                  AND t2.LastN  = (Select Last_Name from Table1 where ID = @ID)  
                  AND t2.PhoneN = (Select Phone from Table1 where ID = @ID)        
                  )
   BEGIN
    .... 
  END
```

Not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this as I am doing a subquery for each field..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is looking for records in Table2 that do not match the record in Table1 with an ID of @ID.   Using an INNER JOIN here would be better than using the multiple subqueries:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM FROM Table1 t1
               INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
                  ON  t1.First_Name = t2.FirstN
                  AND t1.Last_Name = t2.LastN
                  AND t1.Phone = t2.PhoneN
              WHERE t1.ID = @ID)
BEGIN
    ....
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to compare execution plans to see how the performance compares, but this seems a little cleaner to me:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2
ON t1.First_Name = t2.FirstN
   AND t1.Last_Name = t2.LastN
   AND t1.Phone = t2.PHone
WHERE t2.Iden IS NULL
```

Comment: I think that this should be a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Nate's sample code is checking to see if there any any records in Table2 that match a record in Table1 for a specific ID (@ID).  This doesn't really accomplish that -- it gets -all- of the records in Table1 with no match in Table2.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at the [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) keyword. The brief definition of the EXCEPT functionality is

> EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not
>   also found on the right query.

The solution using your example tables would be, 
    SELECT t1.First_Name, t1.Last_Name, t1.Phone FROM Table1 t1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT t2.First_Name, t2.Last_Name, t2.Phone FROM Table2 t2